# Convert from Java UUID to an android UUID

Tags: java, android, uuid

I have an UUID like this:

```
0xbb886aeb-36b5-4c85-8652-c823d300997e
```

Represented as Hex, if am not mistaken. I want to use this UUID in my android application like this:

```
 tmp = adapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord("My Profile", UUID.fromString("0xbb886aeb-36b5-4c85-8652-c823d300997e"));
```

But this gives me the following error

```
07-27 10:55:26.105: E/AndroidRuntime(5313): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "0xbb886aeb"
```

How can I manage to "translate" this `UUID` to a `String` so I can create a `ServerSocket`? I **need** to use this specific `UUID`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the 0x from the front of your string and, I believe, you have your solution.

ie:

```
tmp = adapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord("My Profile", UUID.fromString("bb886aeb-36b5-4c85-8652-c823d300997e"));
```

Comment: The `0x` is a convention for indicating that the value to follow is a [hexadecimal (hex)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) value.

Answer (score 2):

The x is not a hex value, so it cannot be converted to a UUID.